# Is there a way to know from the command line which files TextWrangler currently has open?

Tags: scripting, edit, textwrangler

TextWranger comes with it's command-line tool, "edit", which allows me to open a file for editing on the command-line. The problem is, the "edit" program ends (returns control to the calling program) as soon as it sends the command to TextWrangler to open a file.

This can create a problem if I want to use TextWrangler as my editor-of-choice for a script designed with tools like "vi" in mind, which cause the shell that causes them to wait until the editing is complete and the file is closed.

Now, in theory, I know a way I can get around this. I can write a wrapper script which does three things: (1) calls "edit" with whichever file I am wishing to edit (2) continues it's run, checking over and over (no more frequently than every second - but could by preference be adjusted to do this *less* frequently) to see whether TextWrangler still has the file I asked it to edit open and (3) ending it's execution only once TextWrangler no longer has the file open.

Of course, this is something that I currently only can do in theory -- to bring the theory to actual practice there is one more thing I would need to know --- and that is, *is* there a way for a script to check from the command-line what files TextWrangler currently has open -- or better yet, whether or not it still has open the specific file that I am concerned with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--wait` for both `twdiff` and `edit`. I use this extensively with vim, as well as svn/git: without those flags, the temp files are immediately removed and `diff`ing or editing them causes errors as the original file can't be found.

It also lets you cycle through multiple files and the next file won't be opened until the last one has been closed.

See `twdiff -?` or `edit -?` for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) I just tried your answer out, and it works perfectly. :-) Previously, I was wondering if I'd ever find the information I need to write that wrapper script I spoke of. :-) Now, I may not need to write a wrapper script at all - and if I do, all that wrapper script will need to do will be to add the "-w" (a.k.a. "--wait") option. :-) Thanks. :-)

Comment: Glad the answer helped. As kind of an aside, sometimes `twdiff` won't work correctly when multiple files are involved, and `twdiff` is used in a script (such as for doing diffs for `git`), and a script line this is necessary: `/usr/local/bin/twdiff --wait --resume "$2" "$5" | cat`.  Notice the pipe `|` and `cat` at the end: For some reason, those help the script work on ALL the supplied files, instead of dying after the first one.

Comment: Yes --- though unless [tag:git] adds a crucial feature, I have no intent to use it in any project of mine. The crucial feature I would require is the ability to have medium-depth clones -- which unlike shallow clones can fully participate in the project as a whole (including generating, pushing, and pulling commits) -- but which unlike a full clone does not need to contain the _entire_ history of the project - just the whole history of the project as of a certain date, as well as the origin-info of the version of every file that existed at the time that the medium-depth history begins.